# Using Cron to open and visit URL's

Tags: cron

I've been working on a script to run from `/etc/cron.daily` to run everyday at 5:00 AM, script works but it doesn't seem to run after I've set all the right executive permissions.

My script is using `XDG-OPEN` to open up a website in a web browser, but even after setting permissions to execute, ie; `chmod +x` it doesn't run like it's suppose to. because in my own crontab ->> `crontab -e` I've made my cron job scheduled to run at 5:00AM everyday linking to the script inside of `/etc/cron.daily`

here's my script that I use so get clear picture how it's setup;

```
#!/bin/sh

LOG=/var/log/website_open.log
DATE=`date +'%a, %e %b %T %p'`

echo "*** Website opened on  [ $DATE ]***" >> $LOG
echo " " >> $LOG

xdg-open http://example.com | grep -v "Created new window in existing browser session." >> $LOG
```

When I check the log it says it executed on which date, but it's not been doing what it's suppose to. So the logs would say this

```
*** Website opened on  [ Mon, 24 Nov 01:04:41 AM ] ***
```

but it didn't really execute it properly. I did do `run-parts -v` to check if it worked alright, and it does, cuz it did execute properly and opened up the website after running that, but the problem is Cron isn't running it like when I tested it with `run-parts -v` for some reason. It's like it's being ignored, there doesn't seem to be a permission issue, because if it did it would of shown up in the logs like *"Google Chrome can not run as Root"* since that's my default browser to run as.

I don't believe there is anything wrong with my script since `xdg-open http://example.com` runs as expected from the script when tested, and in my crontab when I do `crontab -e` I have it set like this;

```
0 0 5 1/1 * ? *  /etc/cron.daily/example_com
```

but still doesn't execute as it should be. I have thought about whether I should just execute the script from my home directory and using it with crontab, but I don't really like how crontab works since it only creates a temporary file like this;

```
/tmp/crontab.CjOKO9/crontab
```

and I just want it to be in an actual script of it's own it just runs from instead of being in a temporary file, not sure if that's entirely possible since I want it to run as my user account name and not root.

Comment: unanswered questions with no answers

Comment: Still no answers… uh… Hello? is anybody seeing this?

Comment: Answers! Answers! Answers! I'm looking for answers, nobody know how to do anything?

Comment: I want to set a bounty to this question since this is a unique question, but there's no option to do so cuz this is gone unanswered still from 20 days ago…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `xdg-open` doesn't work correctly when used in association with `crontab`.

You can tweak your way around to get the job done by using any of the following commands :
           `chromium-browser http://www.google.com`
            or
           `firefox http://www.google.com`
based on your browser.